# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^1 nx(1-x^2)^n \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate the integral $\int_0^1 nx(1-x^2)^n \, dx$ ($n$ is constant here)

I actually have the solution which is:

$$\int_0^1 nx(1-x^2)^n = \left( \frac{-n}{2(n+1)} (1-x^2)^{n+1}\right)|_0^1 = \frac{n}{2(n+1)}$$

It's unclear to me this was calculated. I'd be glad for reasoning.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you write $f(x) = 1-x^2$, your integral can be rewriten as

$$\int_0^1 nx(1-x^2)^n = \int_0^1 -\frac{n}{2} f'(x)f(x)^n dx $$

$$ = \int_0^1 -\frac{n}{2(n+1)} \left( f(x)^{n+1} \right)' dx$$

$$ = \left[-\frac{n}{2(n+1)} f^{n+1}(x)\right]_0^1$$

Answer (score 2):

We want to integrate $f(x)=nx(1-x^2)^n$

Let $u=1-x^2$ and thus $du=-2xdx$

$\int{f(x)dx}=\frac{-1}{2}\int{n\cdot u^n (-2x)dx}=\frac{-1}{2}\int{nu^ndu}=-\frac{nu^{n+1}}{2(n+1)}+c=-\frac{n(1-x^2)^{n+1}}{2(n+1)}+c$

Integrating from 0 to 1, we get $\frac{n}{2(n+1)}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: change of variable $x^2=t$.

Comment: Not sure how this helps

Comment: The other two answers use this change of variable (although it is not explicitly said.) It seems to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\text{If } u = (1 - x^2)^k,\ du = k(1-x^2)^{k-1}(-2x) dx= -2kx(1-x^2)^{k-1}dx$$
Then
$$\int nx(1-x^2)^n dx = -\frac{n}{2(n+1)}\int (n+1)(-2x)(1-x^2)^n dx$$
$$= -\frac{n}{2(n+1)}\int (1-x^2)^n\left((n+1)(-2x)\ dx\right)$$